# How to prevent XSD.EXE from collapsing nested types to a jagged array in generated C#?

Tags: c#, xsd, xsd.exe

Consider the following XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="ContainingClass" type="ContainingClass" />

  <xs:complexType name="ContainingClass">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="OuterArrayContainer" type="OuterArrayContainer" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="OuterArrayContainer">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="10" name="OuterArray" type="InnerArrayContainer" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="InnerArrayContainer">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="10" name="InnerArray" type="xs:int" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Assuming that the above XSD is in a file called "test.xsd", I can run the following command to create a C# wrapper for it:

```
xsd test.xsd /c
```

The C# output looks like this (after removing XML attributes for brevity):

```
public partial class ContainingClass {

    private int[][] outerArrayContainerField;

    public int[][] OuterArrayContainer {
        get { return this.outerArrayContainerField; }
        set { this.outerArrayContainerField = value; }
    }
}
```

As you can see, it has lost the inner types altogether and replaced them with a single jagged `int` array. I want to preserve the inner types.

If I add dummy elements to the XSD like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="ContainingClass" type="ContainingClass" />

  <xs:complexType name="ContainingClass">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="OuterArrayContainer" type="OuterArrayContainer" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="OuterArrayContainer">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="10" name="OuterArray" type="InnerArrayContainer" />
      <xs:element name="Dummy" type="xs:int" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="InnerArrayContainer">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="10" name="InnerArray" type="xs:int" />
      <xs:element name="Dummy" type="xs:int" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Then the output is:

```
public partial class ContainingClass {

    private OuterArrayContainer outerArrayContainerField;

    public OuterArrayContainer OuterArrayContainer {
        get { return this.outerArrayContainerField; }
        set { this.outerArrayContainerField = value; }
    }
}

public partial class OuterArrayContainer {

    private InnerArrayContainer[] outerArrayField;

    private int dummyField;

    public InnerArrayContainer[] OuterArray {
        get { return this.outerArrayField; }
        set { this.outerArrayField = value; }
    }

    public int Dummy {
        get { return this.dummyField; }
        set { this.dummyField = value; }
    }
}

public partial class InnerArrayContainer {

    private int[] innerArrayField;

    private int dummyField;

    public int[] InnerArray {
        get { return this.innerArrayField; }
        set { this.innerArrayField = value; }
    }

    public int Dummy {
        get { return this.dummyField; }
        set { this.dummyField = value; }
    }
}
```

This preserves the inner types, but at the expense of having an unused dummy property.

My question is: Is there a way to do this without introducing a dummy element (and without having to go and manually edit the output C# code)?

(It's entirely possibly that I'm going about this in completely the wrong way...)

Comment: I can't tell if [svcutil with /dconly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/servicemodel-metadata-utility-tool-svcutil-exe) would do a better job but that would require you construct a wsdl with endpoints that uses your types from test,xsd. It is worth a try if nothng else comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is: Is there a way to do this without introducing a dummy element (and without having to go and manually edit the output C# code)?

Short answer is no. In this particular instance, this seems like a bug with **XSD.exe**, but even then, it has always had poor support for complex types in general, as its generated code is heavily serialization/deserialization-oriented, not schema-oriented, so it makes only the bare minimum effort to model schema semantics.

What I recommend using is another tool called **'dotnet-xscgen'** from https://github.com/mganss/XmlSchemaClassGenerator (view instructions on how to install/use it [here](https://github.com/mganss/XmlSchemaClassGenerator?tab=readme-ov-file#usage))

It generates code that is still very similar to **XSD.exe** (i.e. `XmlSerializer` compatible) but is much improved. When running your original schema (without the dummy elements), it generates the following code (I've removed all attributes for brevity):

```
// This code was generated by XmlSchemaClassGenerator version 2.1.1057.0 using the following command:
// xscgen schema.xsd --namespace=Default
public partial class ContainingClass
{
    private System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<InnerArrayContainer> _outerArrayContainer;
    public System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<InnerArrayContainer> OuterArrayContainer {
        get {
            return _outerArrayContainer;
        }
        private set {
            _outerArrayContainer = value;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// <para xml:lang="en">Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ContainingClass" /> class.</para>
    /// </summary>
    public ContainingClass() {
        this._outerArrayContainer = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<InnerArrayContainer>();
    }
}
public partial class OuterArrayContainer
{
    private System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<InnerArrayContainer> _outerArray;
    public System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<InnerArrayContainer> OuterArray {
        get {
            return _outerArray;
        }
        private set {
            _outerArray = value;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// <para xml:lang="en">Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="OuterArrayContainer" /> class.</para>
    /// </summary>
    public OuterArrayContainer() {
        this._outerArray = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<InnerArrayContainer>();
    }
}
public partial class InnerArrayContainer
{
    private System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<int> _innerArray;
    public System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<int> InnerArray {
        get {
            return _innerArray;
        }
        private set {
            _innerArray = value;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// <para xml:lang="en">Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="InnerArrayContainer" /> class.</para>
    /// </summary>
    public InnerArrayContainer() {
        this._innerArray = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<int>();
    }
}
```

Microsoft do not appear to be interested in [improving XML tooling](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/better-xsd-xml-tooling/426740) so others have taken up the slack.